# os.pathconf() keys and their meaning

Tags: python, unix, constants

The [documentation for `os.pathconf()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.pathconf) (or the same for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathconf)) only vaguely alludes to a set of keys whose meaning is specified in various other places;

> Return system configuration information relevant to a named file. `name` specifies the configuration value to retrieve; it may be a string which is the name of a defined system value; these names are specified in a number of standards (POSIX.1, Unix 95, Unix 98, and others). Some platforms define additional names as well. The names known to the host operating system are given in the `pathconf_names` dictionary.

So I can fetch and examine `pathconf_names`;

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.pathconf_names
{'PC_MAX_INPUT': 3, 'PC_VDISABLE': 9, 'PC_SYNC_IO': 25,
'PC_NAME_MAX': 4, 'PC_MAX_CANON': 2, 'PC_PRIO_IO': 19,
'PC_CHOWN_RESTRICTED': 7, 'PC_ASYNC_IO': 17, 'PC_NO_TRUNC': 8,
'PC_FILESIZEBITS': 18, 'PC_LINK_MAX': 1, 'PC_PIPE_BUF': 6,
'PC_PATH_MAX': 5}
```

and guess what some of these labels mean.  But where would I go and look up their precise semantics?  The labels are clearly specific to this interface; searching for `PC_LINK_MAX` brings up [documentation for a similar interface in z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxb600/pcf.htm) (sic!) <sup>1</sup> and pages in Japanese for Ruby etc. but nothing specifically about Python or what the "some platforms define additional names as well" might mean.  This TutorialsPoint article is about Python: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_pathconf.htm but it's just a tutorial.

Where would I find useful documentation for this interface, specifically about what labels are available in Python on various platforms, and what their values mean?

(The Python docs say "Availability: Unix" so that apparently restricts the set of possible platforms somewhat.  A clarification for what "some platforms" means here would be a nice bonus.)

---

1. Even more than Microsoft, IBM seems to run a link rot bot which takes care to move any content anybody ever links to as soon as it notices; so the URL is unlikely to work any longer now. Sorry.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Duh, thanks! Would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posix platforms: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html (just drop the PC_ to find the definitions)

Comment: Eight months later and the IBM link still works.  Wow, I guess their bot had a malfunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`pathconf` manual (Linux)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pathconf):

> - **_PC_LINK_MAX** returns the maximum number of links to the file. If fd or path refer to a directory, then the value applies to the whole
>     directory. The corresponding macro is _POSIX_LINK_MAX.
> - **_PC_MAX_CANON** returns the maximum length of a formatted input line, where fd or path must refer to a terminal. The corresponding macro is
>     _POSIX_MAX_CANON.
> - **_PC_MAX_INPUT** returns the maximum length of an input line, where fd or path must refer to a terminal. The corresponding macro is
>     _POSIX_MAX_INPUT.
> - **_PC_NAME_MAX** returns the maximum length of a filename in the directory path or fd that the process is allowed to create. The corresponding
>     macro is _POSIX_NAME_MAX.
> - **_PC_PATH_MAX** returns the maximum length of a relative pathname when path or fd is the current working directory. The corresponding macro
>     is _POSIX_PATH_MAX.
> - **_PC_PIPE_BUF** returns the size of the pipe buffer, where fd must refer to a pipe or FIFO and path must refer to a FIFO. The corresponding
>     macro is _POSIX_PIPE_BUF.
> - **_PC_CHOWN_RESTRICTED** returns nonzero if the chown(2) call may not be used on this file. If fd or path refer to a directory, then this
>     applies to all files in that directory. The corresponding macro is
>     _POSIX_CHOWN_RESTRICTED.
> - **_PC_NO_TRUNC** returns nonzero if accessing filenames longer than _POSIX_NAME_MAX generates an error. The corresponding macro is _POSIX_NO_TRUNC.
> - **_PC_VDISABLE** returns nonzero if special character processing can be disabled, where fd or path must refer to a terminal.

From the [`pathconf` manual (FreeBSD)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pathconf&sektion=2):

```
 _PC_LINK_MAX
     The maximum file link count.

 _PC_MAX_CANON
     The maximum number of bytes in terminal canonical input line.

 _PC_MAX_INPUT
     The minimum maximum number of bytes for which space is available
     in a terminal input queue.

 _PC_NAME_MAX
     The maximum number of bytes in a file name.

 _PC_PATH_MAX
     The maximum number of bytes in a pathname.

 _PC_PIPE_BUF
     The maximum number of bytes which will be written atomically to a
     pipe.

 _PC_CHOWN_RESTRICTED
     Return 1 if appropriate privilege is required for the chown(2)
     system call, otherwise 0.  IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'')
     requires appropriate privilege in all cases, but this behavior
     was optional in prior editions of the standard.

 _PC_NO_TRUNC
     Return greater than zero if attempts to use pathname components
     longer than {NAME_MAX} will result in an [ENAMETOOLONG] error;
     otherwise, such components will be truncated to {NAME_MAX}.  IEEE
     Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'') requires the error in all cases,
     but this behavior was optional in prior editions of the standard,
     and some non-POSIX-compliant file systems do not support this
     behavior.

 _PC_VDISABLE
     Returns the terminal character disabling value.

 _PC_ASYNC_IO
     Return 1 if asynchronous I/O is supported, otherwise 0.

 _PC_PRIO_IO
     Returns 1 if prioritised I/O is supported for this file, other-
     wise 0.

 _PC_SYNC_IO
     Returns 1 if synchronised I/O is supported for this file, other-
     wise 0.

 _PC_ALLOC_SIZE_MIN
     Minimum number of bytes of storage allocated for any portion of a
     file.

 _PC_FILESIZEBITS
     Number of bits needed to represent the maximum file size.

 _PC_REC_INCR_XFER_SIZE
     Recommended increment for file transfer sizes between
     _PC_REC_MIN_XFER_SIZE and _PC_REC_MAX_XFER_SIZE.

 _PC_REC_MAX_XFER_SIZE
     Maximum recommended file transfer size.

 _PC_REC_MIN_XFER_SIZE
     Minimum recommended file transfer size.

 _PC_REC_XFER_ALIGN
     Recommended file transfer buffer alignment.

 _PC_SYMLINK_MAX
     Maximum number of bytes in a symbolic link.

 _PC_ACL_EXTENDED
     Returns 1 if an Access Control List (ACL) can be set on the spec-
     ified file, otherwise 0.

 _PC_ACL_NFS4
     Returns 1 if an NFSv4 ACLs can be set on the specified file, oth-
     erwise 0.

 _PC_ACL_PATH_MAX
     Maximum number of ACL entries per file.

 _PC_CAP_PRESENT
     Returns 1 if a capability state can be set on the specified file,
     otherwise 0.

 _PC_INF_PRESENT
     Returns 1 if an information label can be set on the specified
     file, otherwise 0.

 _PC_MAC_PRESENT
     Returns 1 if a Mandatory Access Control (MAC) label can be set on
     the specified file, otherwise 0.

 _PC_MIN_HOLE_SIZE
     If a file system supports the reporting of holes (see lseek(2)),
     pathconf() and fpathconf() return a positive number that repre-
     sents the minimum hole size returned in bytes.  The offsets of
     holes returned will be aligned to this same value.  A special
     value of 1 is returned if the file system does not specify the
     minimum hole size but still reports holes.
```

Comment: Note that on many platforms, the results may lie or be infinite.